# Function parameters not working with .classList.add

Tags: javascript

I have created a simple function to remove and add classes but I cannot get it to work, below is the html to test on, it needs to work so that when the mouse enters '.dropdown' then #myDropdown will get a class added to it 'show' and when the mouse leaves then the class will be removed:

```js
const dropDown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');
const dropDownList = dropDown.querySelector('#myDropdown');
const classToToggle = 'show';
dropDown.addEventListener("mouseenter", toggleClass(dropDownList, classToToggle));
dropDown.addEventListener("mouseleave", toggleClass(dropDownList, classToToggle));

function toggleClass(target, className) {
    if(target.classList.contains(className)) {
        target.classList.remove(className);
    } else {
        target.classList.add(className);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" style="outline: none;">Dropdown <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            <p>Item 1</p>
            <p>Item 2</p>
            <p>Item 3</p>
            <p>Item 4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The function just isn't adding 'className' to the 'target' even though when I console.log the 'className and 'target' parameters they both seem to have come through okay.

Thanks

Comment: Your calls to `.addEventListener()` are wrong. Your code *calls* the `toggleClass()` function and passes the return value to `.addEventListener()`. You have to wrap the calls to `toggleClass()` in another anonymous function.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why this has to be done with JavaScript? https://jsfiddle.net/rsgz8wcv/

Comment: Doing this in Javascript purely for learning purposes, appreciate the CSS answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addEventListener` expects a callback function, not a function call result (which happens in your case). Wrap your function in another function to fix the issue:

```
dropDown.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => toggleClass(dropDownList, classToToggle));
dropDown.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => toggleClass(dropDownList, classToToggle));
```